# Can you automate the renaming of postgres databases via a ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I find myself cloning production database locally into my local development database for a rails 4.2 project.  Sometimes I add test migrations (or remove certain columns of data).

Currently I use `ALTER DATABASE development RENAME TO development_preserve_production_data` when I'm testing new migrations.

Can I automate this via Ruby script?  Or should I (can I) automate this via a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate it with Ruby/ActiveRecord using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('<raw sql command>')`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER DATABASE development RENAME TO development_preserve_production_data')
```

You can also do it in migrations by simply using the `execute` command:

```
SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "<some sql command>"
  end
end
```